# CommandButton event not firing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am populating an html table from a datatable with an edit button in each table row for each datatable row.

I am adding the edit button in code as follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (UserName != null && UserName != "")
            {
                hUserName.Value = UserName;
            }
            else
                if (hUserName.Value != "")
                    UserName = hUserName.Value;
            ShowTrainingEntry();
            ShowUserTraining();  <-------------- this method populates table
            hTID.Value = TrainingID.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void ShowUserTraining()
    {
       ....

                        dTotalTrainingHours += ShowTrainingInPeriod(dv);
       ....
    }

    protected decimal ShowTrainingInPeriod(DataView dv)
    {
       ....
        foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv)
        {
            ....
            Button bEdit = new Button();
            int iTID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"].ToString());
            bEdit.Text = "Edit";
            bEdit.ID = "btnEdit_" + iTID.ToString();
            bEdit.CommandName = "Edit";
            bEdit.CommandArgument = iTID.ToString();
            bEdit.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnEdit_Click);
            ....
        }
        ....
    }

    public void btnEdit_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        clsLog.WriteLog("btnEdit_Click fired.");
        clsLog.WriteLog("\t" + e.CommandName);
        clsLog.WriteLog("\t" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        UserName = hUserName.Value;
        TrainingID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        ShowTrainingEntry();
        ShowUserTraining();
    }
```

as requested - HTML table:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblMain" runat="server" Width="900" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="0" CssClass="noborder">
</asp:Table>
```

btnEdit_Click is NOT being fired (no log entries).

I have researched this for several hours and the only thing consistent I have found is that the event must be wired to the button during Page_Load which I believe is happening correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Use a GridView. It has all that functionality already builtin.

Comment: Can we see the HTML table please. My guess is that the button isn't running server side. (`runat="server"`)

Comment: Can't use gridview for this application. The original app was classic ASP and had white space separating the periods (years) which management wanted to retain.  Technically I could use gridview but the programming to insert whitespace between periods would be a nightmare!  I would have to trap every row during the databound event and insert "blank" rows between periods.  In any case the commandbutton method SHOULD work.

Comment: As to runat="server": not an option for code-created buttons.

Comment: OK. I relented and used the gridview and added the extra rows in the RowDataBoundevent. However, now the gridview indexes are all messed up and the edit function fails because it doesn't have the correct index. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Final resolution: I added code in the SQL stored Procedure to create header and footer rows. Then, I used the RowDataBound event to format accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try to do event register

```
btnEdit_Click.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEdit_Click);
```

Comment: btnEdit_Click is a method; not an object.